# MySQL Database Structure - Storing Facebook FQL Results

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, structure, facebook-fql

I'm using FQL to query the [Facebook Insights table](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/insights/) and return the data to my server, where I plan to store it within a MySQL database.

I've found that all the Insights metrics return different data types for the value field. For example, something like **application_installation_adds** will return a value like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [metric] => application_installation_adds
            [value] => 3
        )

)
```

..while a metric like **application_permission_views_top** will return this if it has data:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [metric] => application_permission_views_top
            [value] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [permissions_impression_email] => 5
                    [permissions_impression_user_birthday] => 4
                    [permissions_impression_read_insights] => 4
                )

        )

)
```

..and this if it's empty:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [metric] => application_permission_views_top
            [value] => Array
                (
                )

        )

)
```

Given the different data types and values, I was wondering what the best way to store this data within my database would be.

I was thinking of setting up a table like this:

- metric_name
- metric_subname
- value

and then using a process like this:

1. Get FQL result.
2. If it's an empty Array, do nothing *(because there is no data)*.
3. If it's a single value, insert metric_name and value. Give the metric_subname a value of "Singlular" *(so that I know it's just a one-value metric)*.
4. If it's a stdCLass Object, use a foreach loop to fill in the metric_subname column.

This should give me a table like so, which will allow me to query the data in an easy manner down the track: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fekJ.png

Can anyone please provide feedback? Is this a good way to go about it, or are there better options?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Why do you want to persist data instead of just caching it?

Comment: For some of the metrics FQL only gives the current value. Eg. if I queried my fanpage it'll give me the current fan count. The reason I want to store the FQL results in a database is so that I can have a historical record as to how my fans have grown by day etc.

Comment: doesn't facebook provide such kind of statistic?

Comment: Unfortunately not. :( For example, the page_fans metric only gives you the current number of fans - there's no way of getting historical info for it!

Comment: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/insights/ --- not the fans, but some kind of stats

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you know how many levels deep the hierarchy of metrics can go?  If more than two, your solution doesn't scale.

Assume at some point depth will reach > 2 and design a generalized schema.  One that comes to mind would be to keep two tables: metrics, and user_metrics.  The metrics table would just contain the hierarchy of possible metrics, with one change: instead of name and subname, implement id, name, parent_id.  The second table would associate a metric with a user, and store the value, so: metric_id, user_id, value.

Comment: Many thanks AJ! I hadn't thought about scalability issues so your solution is perfect! :)